# What are the forward slashes in regex functions used for?

Tags: php, regex

Why do `preg_match` for PHP and other regex functions of other languages have delimiters like `//` in the string denoting the pattern to be searched for?

I have almost no experience with regex, but the reason for having two of these delimiters denoting the start and end of a `pattern` string isn't obvious to me, because you could just use the start and end of the string.

Comment: And you haven't found answer of this in PHP docs OR anywhere else?

Comment: Holy crap, I'm an idiot @anubhava . Okay, the reason is obvious now.  A place to put flags at the end of the strings. For example (PHP docs): `// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search` .  What's the appropriate course of action, since this is a trivial question...to close my question now?

Comment: If you want you can just delete your answer.

Comment: The title says 'backslashes', but in the text you have (forward) slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, backslashes are escapes. They REMOVE significance from a character so that the charcter's treated as what it literally looks like. In other cases, backslashes ADD significance to a char, turning it into a metacharacter. e.g in regexes:

```
/d/   - look for a character "d"
/\d/  - look for a digit: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9, aka [0-9] - adding significance
/\\/  - look for a literal \ char - REMOVING significance
```

The // are forward slashes. They're just the default standard delimiters, because those are the standard delimiters used in Perl, and PHP implements PCRE - Perl-compatible Regular Expressions.

```
$m =~ /d/  - perl for matching a "d" character in a string
$m =~ /\d/ - perl for matching a digit
```

In PHP, because the regexes are just strings, not part of the core language, you can use any delimiter you want. The first char in your pattern becomes the delimiter:

```
preg_match('/foo/', $str)   #1, using / forward slashes as delimiter
preg_match('|foo|', $str)   #2, using | pipes as delimiters 
preg_match('f\foof', $str)  #3, using the letter F as delimiter
```

Note now you can use any char you want. `f` In the 3rd regex is the first char of the pattern, so it's the delimiter. Which means that if you're using that regex to look for an "f" in your text, you need to escape that F (`\f`), so that the internal F is seen as JUST an f, not as the pattern delimiter

Answer (score 0):

PHP is using Perl-style regular expressions, so I guess, Perl 'invented' this syntax.

These delimiters are used to add certain modifiers to the regular expression. Of course PHP could also use flags in the function call or something like that to do this but that would change the syntax from Perl.

So I think these delimiters are used for historical purposes.